# xcode ld: library not found for -lPods

Tags: xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

When I try compile my project which used CocoaPods I have following linking error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The reason of this problem is version of CocoaPods. Project was cloned from repo, then pods was installed. But my version of cocoapods is 1.0.1. Version of cocoapods which declared in Podfile.lock  is 0.39.0.

**Solution is following(In terminal):**
*1) Uninstall CocoaPods.*
`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

*2) Install version of cocoapods which declared in the Podfile.lock*
`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0`

*3) You can check version cocoapods:*
`gem which cocoapods`

*4) Clone project  then install dependencies*
`pod install`